# "Default" project-named Repo deletion by terraform in code

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to have only my "defined" repository with resource "azuredevops_git_repository" [MyRepo] and not have the system generated one uninitalized with project name [MyProject], is it possible somehow on code level ?

Provider : Terraform-azuredevops
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/git_repository

```
resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "repo" {
  project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
  name       = "MyRepo"
  default_branch = "refs/heads/develop"
  initialization {
    init_type = "Clean"
}
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      initialization,
      ]
    }
  }

resource "azuredevops_project" "project" {
  name               = "MyProject"
  description        = "MyDescription"
  visibility         = "private"
  version_control    = "Git"
  work_item_template = "Agile"
}
```

Could you please help me to find and elaborate on this answer ?

Thank you in advance,

After I deleted the default repository from the Web UI of Azure DevOps, Terraform did not indicated any change on the code level, So I can not understand how can I prevent the "default" repository creation on code level e.g. by the resource "azuredevops_git_repository" or the project definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my knowledge, the Terraform-Azure DevOps provider can be used to configure Azure DevOps project in Microsoft Azure using [Azure DevOps Service REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

For the [create project rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP), there isn't a parameter to change the default repo name.

Thus here are two ways for your reference:
1.After creating a new project->do your shown 'create defined name repo' step, you could call corresponding [delete repo rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP) to delete the default repo (since a project needs at least one repo exists).
2.After creating a new project, you could directly rename the default repo by calling [the rest api update repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&tabs=HTTP).

I hope it could do some help.

Comment: Yes that was definitely useful, thanks. Unfortunately, I have encountered the limitation of AzureDevOps terraform provider many times not only this case, such as the lack of artifact or release pipeline access definition which is unavailable yet in the aformentioned module.

To use Azure DevOps Service REST API is definitely a good idea, although I have no experience with the best practices related to that. Could you recommend some best practices or resources apart from official mic.docs, how can I implement these calls into my Terraform .tf script or CI/CD pipeline?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sorry, not very familiar with Terraform-azuredevops provider, but maybe you could try to use powsershell with script to call rest api directly for a try.